# Deny Permission to Folders and Files

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl

I need to Deny an group to C:\Windows\Installer folder/files

I try to use following but it only applies to folder but not all of the files, it is applying to some files

```
$path = "C:\Windows\Installer"
 $acl = Get-Acl $path
 $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("YourUsers","FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Deny")
 $acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
 Set-Acl -AclObject $acl -Path $path
```

Am I missing anything from my script

EDIT:
After checking the permission on files which I can delete, it looks like Inherit is disabled

How can I check to see if Inherit is disable or not and if its disable then enable it

I need to apply this to 5000 machine this is why i'm doing it through script

Comment: The command you provided is doing exactly what it should setting the permissions on a specific folder.  You would have to either set the inheritance on each file or set the permissions on each file that existed before the permissions change. Have you considered just setting it through the Properties window?

Answer (score 0):

You are only applying the ACL change to the folder you specified with `$path`, to apply the ACL to everything in the folder you need to list each item recursively:

```
$path = "C:\Windows\Installer"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $path

# Enables inheritance on all items in folder
foreach ($item in $items)
{
  $acl = Get-acl $item.FullName
  $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false,$true)
  Set-Acl -AclObject -Path $item.FullName
}

# Sets file / folder permission to desired state
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("YourUsers","FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Deny")
foreach ($item in $items)
{
  $acl = Get-acl $item.FullName
  # Compare item's folder permission against root folder, if different apply ACL
  if ((Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-ACL $path) -DifferentObject (Get-ACL $item) -Property access) -ne $null)
  {
    $acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
    Set-Acl -AclObject $item.FullName
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I check it first before apply the permission. I want to make sure the permission is not applied before applying the permission.

Comment: @maj I updated the answer based off your edit.

Comment: I tested the script and it does work but for some reason I can deny the delete of folders but not the files. I can see the deny is applied to files/folders

Comment: What i'm trying to do is stop Aeveto giving admin rights to standard users to this folder

Comment: @maj if that's the case you would simply deny Aeveto write permissions. If you need to be more granular go into special permissions and only deny what you need.

Comment: I deny permission on Windows\installer folder and remove all inherited permission from files/folder but still I can delete files but not the folder. If I put deny permission on the file it works but it doesnt like it if inherited from folder

Comment: Try this doc to inherit file permissions [https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/88305-enable-disable-inherited-permissions-objects-windows.html](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/88305-enable-disable-inherited-permissions-objects-windows.html)